# How do I mount Zyxel NSA310 shares?

Tags: mount, nas, smb

I have a Zyxel NSA310 NAS, which is working fine with Windows machines in the house. I've also successfully created and mounted an NFS share on the two Ubuntu machines.

But I'd like to mount the standard Windows shares (photo, music and video), and I've had no luck. File manager finds the homestore (the NSA310's default name) on the network but won't let me drill down. Going straight to smb: doesn't work. And editing /etc/fstab with plausible-looking entries yields errors.

Does anyone have experience of this useful device? Surely I'm not the only one who's wrestled with it?!

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the fastest way is to mount via `cifs`. Run the following command (by making necessary changes):

```
mount -t cifs //se.rv.er.IP/video /ubuntu_path -o rw,user=xxx,password=yyy
```

If you don't have `cifs` installed; you may do so by running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install cifs
```

Answer (score 0):

I know, old question, but for me it works like this, this is my line from /etc/fstab:

```
//192.168.1.100/video /media/local-folder cifs credentials=/home/user1/.smbcredentialsWrite,vers=1.0,noauto,rw,gid=1000,uid=1000 0 0
```

where my ~/.smbcredentialsWrite contains login credentials in form:

```
username=uuuuuu
password=ppppp
```

I think that in my case catch was that NSA310S is sharing with smb 1.0 - older version.